# Simplify process with linq query

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, performance, linq

This is my Table:

**PupilNutrition**

```
Id     PupilId   NutritionId
1       10          100  
2       10          101
```

My another table **Nutrition**:

```
Id  Nutritioncategory  BatchId   NutritionRate   NutritionId   Operation
1       A                1         9000             100          1
2       B                1         5000             100          0
3       C                1         5000             100          1
4       D                2         6000             101          2           
5       E                2         7000             101          2         
6       F                2         8000             101          0
```

This is one field to store final **Rate**:

```
decimal Rate= 0;
```

**Case 1**: **Operation field with Value 0 and Batch Id 1**

```
 Rate= Rate + NutritionRate(i.e 5000 because for batch id 1 with condition 0 only 1 record is there).
```

**Case 2**:**Now for operation field with Value 1 and Batch Id 1**

```
Here i want to sum up both the value i.e(10000 and 5000) but during addition if sum of both is greater than 10000 then just take 10000 else take sum like this:
if(9000 + 5000 > 10000)
  Rate= 10000
else
    Rate=Rate + (Addition of both if less than 10000).
```

**Case 3**:**Now for operation field with Value 0 and Batch Id 2**

```
 Rate= Rate + NutritionRate(i.e 8000 because for batch id 1 with condition 0 only 1 record is there).
```

**Case 4**:**Now for operation field with Value 2 and Batch Id 2**

```
Here I will select Maximum value from Nutrition Rate field if there are 2 records:
Rate=Rate - (Maximum value from 6000 and 7000 so will take 7000).
```

My Class file:

```
 public partial class PupilNutrition
    {
        public int Id { get; set; }
        public int PupilId { get; set; }
        public int NutritionId { get; set; }
    }

 public partial class Nutrition
    {
        public int Id { get; set; }
        public string Nutritioncategory { get; set; }
        public decimal NutritionRate  { get; set; }
        public Nullable<int> NutritionId { get; set; }
    }
```

This is how i have Done:

```
batchId=1 or 2;//
 List<int> NutritionId = db.PupilNutrition.Where(x => PupilId  == 10).Select(c => c.NutritionId).ToList();  //output 100,101
 var data = db.Nutrition.Where(x => x.BatchId == batchId && NutritionId.Contains(x.NutritionId.Value)).ToList();
```

I have tried like this but its a labour process:

```
var data1=data.where(t=>t.Operation==0);
Rate= Rate + data1.Sum(p => p.NutritionRate);
```

Similarly for Operation 1:

```
var data2=data.where(t=>t.Operation==1);
This is left because here i need to sum up 2 value if two records are there as shown in my above cases and if sum is greater than 10000 than select 10000 else select sum.
```

Similarly for Operation 2:

```
var data3=data.where(t=>t.Operation==2);
Rate= Rate - data3.Max(p => p.NutritionRate);
```

I think i have done a labour process as this can be done even in better way with linq query only i guess.

So can anybody help me to simplify this whole process in linq query or even some better way and provide solution for Operation Value 2 which is left?

Comment: Please clarify - do you want 4 *different* results, or one result, which is case1+case2+case3+case4 ?

Comment: @Rob:Final Result would be as follows:Case 1(Rate) + Case 2(Rate) + Case 3(Rate).There are only 3 conditions that is 0,1,2

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Shortest is not always the best.

Personally, I think that single complex LINQ statement can be hard to read and hard to debug.

Here is what I would do:

```
    public decimal CalculateRate(int pupilId, int batchId)
    {
        return db.Nutrition
            .Where(x => x.BatchId == batchId && db.PupilNutrition.Any(y => y.PupilId == pupilId && y.NutritionId == x.NutritionId))
            .GroupBy(x => x.Operation)
            .Select(CalculateRateForOperationGroup)
            .Sum();
    }

    public decimal CalculateRateForOperationGroup(IGrouping<int, Nutrition> group)
    {
        switch (group.Key)
        {
            case 0:
                // Rate = Sum(x)
                return group.Sum(x => x.NutritionRate);
            case 1:
                // Rate = Min(10000, Sum(x))
                return Math.Min(10000, group.Sum(x => x.NutritionRate));
            case 2:
                // Rate = -Max(x)
                return -group.Max(x => x.NutritionRate);
            default:
                throw new ArgumentException("operation");
        }
    }
```

Then you could use it as follows:

```
var rateForFirstBatch = CalculateRate(10, 1);
var rateForSecondBatch = CalculateRate(10, 2);
```

Comment: It is not allowing me to use like this: .Select(CalculateRateForOperationGroup)

Comment: Could you specify exact error message? I was able to run this code on my machine. You could try to replace `.Select(CalculateRateForOperationGroup)` with `.Select(x => CalculateRateForOperationGroup(x))`

Answer (score 5):

Easier with a group by:

```
int sumMax = 10000;
var group = from n in nutrition
    group n by new { n.Operation, n.BatchId } into g
    select new { BatchId = g.Key.BatchId, 
        Operation = g.Key.Operation, 
        RateSum = g.ToList().Sum(nn => nn.NutritionRate), 
        RateSumMax = g.ToList().Sum(nn => nn.NutritionRate) > sumMax ? sumMax : g.ToList().Sum(nn => nn.NutritionRate), 
        RateMax = g.ToList().Max(nn => nn.NutritionRate) };
var result = from g in group
    select new {
        BatchId = g.BatchId,
        Operation = g.Operation,
        Rate = g.Operation == 1 ? g.RateSumMax :
               g.Operation == 2 ? g.RateMax :
               g.RateSum //default is operation 0
    };
var totalRate = result.Sum(g=>g.Rate);
```

Comment: You havent taken my Conditions(0,1,2) in to considerations in your query like when 0 will be there,1 will be there,2 will be there(max value)

Comment: I added the conditions in my answer, but I'm not sure if I understood your processing requirements (that's why I left those out in the first place).

Comment: The conditions you have checked in the last query you need to check that in your fist query.Like before doing sum or selecting maximum you need to check whether operation value is 0,1, or 2.For Eg:RateSum = g.Condition==1 ? g.ToList().Sum(nn => nn.NutritionRate).

Comment: OP says that you need to subtract Max value, not add it

Answer (score 4):

**Update**
This query looks like it should get the job done for you. Note, I haven't tested it, so there may be a syntax error or two, but the idea seems sound.

```
var rate = db.Nutrition
        .GroupBy(n => new { n.BatchId, n.Operation })
        .Select(g => g.Sum(n => n.NutritionRate) > 10000 ? 10000 : g.Sum(n => n.NutritionRate))
        .Sum();
```

Or, if you want queries for each 'case':

```
rate = db.Nutrition
            .Where(n => n.BatchId == 1 && n.Operation == 0)
            .Sum(n => n.NutritionRate); //Case 1

rate += Math.Min(
            10000,  //Either return 10,000, or the calculation if it's less than 10,000
            db.Nutrition
            .Where(n => n.BatchId == 1 && 
                        n.Operation == 1) //filter based on batch and operation
            .Sum(n => n.NutritionRate) //take the sum of the nutrition rates for that filter
        ); //Case 2

rate += db.Nutrition
            .Where(n => n.BatchId == 2 && n.Operation == 0)
            .Sum(n => n.NutritionRate); //Case 3

rate += Math.Min(
            10000,  //Either return 10,000, or the calculation if it's less than 10,000
            db.Nutrition
            .Where(n => n.BatchId == 2 && 
                        n.Operation == 2) //filter based on batch and operation
            .Sum(n => n.NutritionRate) //take the sum of the nutrition rates for that filter
        ); //Case 4
```

Comment: Cant it be done in a single linq query like Niels V has done because i want to minimize the steps of calculation so

Answer (score 4):

try this. I broke the query to make it clear but you can combine this in  one statement only.

```
        //// Join the collection to get the BatchId
        var query = nutritionColl.Join(pupilNutrition, n => n.NutritionId, p => p.NutritionId, (n, p) => new { BatchId = p.Id, Nutrition = n });

        //// Group by BatchId, Operation
        var query1 = query.GroupBy(i => new { i.BatchId, i.Nutrition.Operation });


        //// Execute Used cases by BatchId, Operation
        var query2 = query1.Select(grp =>
                {
                    decimal rate = decimal.MinValue;
                    if (grp.Count() == 1)
                    {
                        rate = grp.First().Nutrition.NutritionRate;
                    }
                    else if (grp.First().BatchId == 1)
                    {
                        var sum = grp.Sum(i => i.Nutrition.NutritionRate);
                        rate = sum > 10000 ? 10000 : sum;
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        rate = grp.Max(i => i.Nutrition.NutritionRate);
                    }

                    return new { BatchId = grp.First().BatchId, Operation = grp.First().Nutrition.Operation, Rate = rate };
                }
        );

        //// try out put
        foreach (var item in query2)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("{0}  {1} {2} ", item.Operation, item.BatchId, item.Rate);
        }
```

hope it helps

Comment: You should use `grp.Key.BatchId` instead of `grp.First().BatchId`

Comment: OP says that you need to subtract Max value, not add it. It should be `rate = -grp.Max(i => i.Nutrition.NutritionRate);`

Comment: @Kaspars Ozols I will advice to read the statement carefull. "  Here I will select Maximum value from Nutrition Rate field if there are 2 records:
Rate=Rate - (Maximum value from 6000 and 7000 so will take 7000)"   from where 7000 he is picking?

Comment: I read statement once again and it makes perfect sense. There are two records matching by batchId=2 and option=2. One has rate 6000 and other 7000. Pick Max and subtract from total rate. Eg. Rate =-7000

Comment: Do you expect rates in - ve. Secondly I think it is hyphen `-` not minus.